# htaccess skip all following rules for subdomain match

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm having problems with this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/16800319/1283556

My current HTACCESS 301 redirects `example.com` to `https://www.example.com`, adding `www.` and `https://` in as few redirects as possible.

I don't want it to add `www.` or `https://` if the subdomain is `m.example.com` so I thought matching this condition and putting no rule, and using the `[L]` flag to stop doing future conditions would work.

```
RewriteEngine On

# Skip forcing www or https if the 'm' subdomain is being used for mobile
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\. [NC]
RewriteRule - [L]

# Force www. and HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

# Force HTTPS (www. was already there)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Don't remap resources to the index processor, just add SSL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^.*^.ico$$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^.*^.css$$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^.*^.js$$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^.*^.gif$$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^.*^.png$$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^.*^.jpg$$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^.*^.jpeg$$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^.*^.xml$$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^.*^.txt$$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://$1 [R=301,L]

# Remap /page/filter/?query to /index.php?page=page&filter=filter&query
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/*([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/?$ /index.php?page=$1&filter=$2 [QSA]
```

The effect of the above is:

```
example.com »301» https://www.example.com
m.example.com »301» https://www.m.example.com
```

The desired effect is:

```
example.com »301» https://www.example.com
m.example.com (do nothing, just serve content from example.com/mobile)
```

**Server Version: Apache/2.4.10 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4 Apache**

It's worth noting that I got this working as a solution but I consider it a work-around and not a linear solution:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Force www. and HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

# Force HTTPS (www. was already there)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Don't remap resources to the index processor, just add SSL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^.*^.ico$$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^.*^.css$$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^.*^.js$$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^.*^.gif$$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^.*^.png$$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^.*^.jpg$$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^.*^.jpeg$$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^.*^.xml$$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^.*^.txt$$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://$1 [R=301,L]

# Remap /page/filter/?query to /index.php?page=page&filter=filter&query
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/*([a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/?$ /index.php?page=$1&filter=$2 [QSA]
```

Comment: It should work. Completely clear your browser cache and retest.

Comment: I'm under the impression that htaccess isn't actually sent to the client and so isn't actually cached unless it is by the server - but I've never experienced that and don't know how to clear the server's internal cache (if that is indeed what you're suggesting). Either way I've cleared my browser's cache but it still redirects to https://www.m.example.com

Comment: What is the Apache version?

Comment: Server Version: Apache/2.4.10 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4 Apache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original and updated question has two 301 redirect rules that are not good for both SEO rankings or user experience.

You can **combine** both rules i.e. `http -> https` and `force-www` into one and also **take care of excluding `m.` host in the same rule**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!m\.)(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Make sure to keep this rule as very first rule and test it after completely clearing your browser cache.

Comment: My version never did two 301's - but this looks very tidy, I'll give it a shot. I'm worried that if you go to http:// www.example you'll be redirected to https:// www.www.example though - will check. Thanks

Comment: Actually if you send a request with URL as: `http://example.com` then your version will do two 301 redirects. 1st 301 to `https://example.com` and 2nd 301 to `https://www.example.com`. Browser caching might not show but if you test from command line curl then it will both.

Comment: But with my first 301 rule if you go to https//example.com it adds https and www in one hit on the first rule set, and doesn't do it twice. I tested with a 301 redirection service to make sure it was SEO friendly

Comment: Yes but that is already https URL. However if you send `http://example.com` then there will be two redirects.